# Can we log individual user details in R Shiny if i host my application from my pc as server?

Tags: r, cookies, shiny, user-tracking

**Brief about Application:** I am currently working on one project where i have created an application on R Shiny, which captures all details of different candidates where one can update the details and send the status by using mail functionality the moment anyone saves the data. Application will give popup to send updated status to candidate using mail. At this point, functionality is running perfectly fine if they open their own instance of a Shiny application.

**Problem:** We have hosted this application from PC as server, due to all users being on the same network. Currently, individual users are accessing the application using the IP Address of Host machine. The moment someone is updating status and saving into database every time, the last updated user entry in data base gets registered as the details of Host, instead of actual User who has made an update. Also, mail is triggered from host user instead of actual user id.

Is there any option to log individual user details who all are running my application within my organisation using my IP address?

Comment: You might want to go through documentaion on the `session` variable in the server function. In theory, that's where the right data should be. Not sure where exactly.

Comment: Are you using regular shiny or Shiny Server product? Are you joined to a domain?

Comment: @anotherfred i have created this application on R shiny and hosting this application within my organisation network using desktop and all other users are running this application by using my system IP address on which this application is hosted

Comment: Have you looked into setting cookies? https://gist.github.com/calligross/e779281b500eb93ee9e42e4d72448189

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned you could set cookies. You can set a user id `uid`, that will remain constant over sessions per user.

Upon each start of each app usage, the app will check the browser cookies for a `uid` in the cookies. If one is found it will help you identify the user across sessions. If none is found its (probably) a new user and there will be a `uid` assigned.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(magrittr)

if (!dir.exists('www/')) {
  dir.create('www')
}

download.file(
  url = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js',
  destfile = 'www/js.cookie.js'
)

addResourcePath("js", "www")

jsCode <- '
shinyjs.getcookie = function(params) {
  var cookie = Cookies.get(params[0]);
  Shiny.onInputChange("jscookie", [params[0], cookie]);
}

shinyjs.setcookie = function(params) {
  Cookies.set(params[1], escape(params[0]), { expires: 0.5 });
}
'

server <- function(input, output) {

  observe({
    input$set
    js$getcookie("uid")
  })

  checkCookie <- eventReactive(input$jscookie, {
    uid <- input$jscookie[2]
    if(is.null(uid) | is.na(uid)){
      uid <- sample(c(0:9, letters), 30, replace = TRUE) %>% paste(collapse = "")
      js$setcookie(uid, "uid")
    }
    return(uid)
  })

  output$output <- renderText({
    checkCookie()
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  shiny::tags$head(
    # you must copy:
    # https://raw.githubusercontent.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/master/src/js.cookie.js
    # to www/
    shiny::tags$script(src = "js/js.cookie.js")
  ),
  useShinyjs(),

  extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton('set', 'set')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput('output')
    )
  )
)

runApp(
  appDir = shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server),
  port = 9898
)
```

It assumes that the users do not delete the cookies. And to be very precise they will be unique across browser per user.

Code is based on https://gist.github.com/calligross/e779281b500eb93ee9e42e4d72448189.

**js.cookie.min.js:** (As asked for in the comments).

```
/**
 * Minified by jsDelivr using Terser v3.14.1.
 * Original file: /npm/js-cookie@2.2.1/src/js.cookie.js
 * 
 * Do NOT use SRI with dynamically generated files! More information: https://www.jsdelivr.com/using-sri-with-dynamic-files
 */
!function(e){var n;if("function"==typeof define&&define.amd&&(define(e),n=!0),"object"==typeof exports&&(module.exports=e(),n=!0),!n){var t=window.Cookies,o=window.Cookies=e();o.noConflict=function(){return window.Cookies=t,o}}}(function(){function e(){for(var e=0,n={};e<arguments.length;e++){var t=arguments[e];for(var o in t)n[o]=t[o]}return n}function n(e){return e.replace(/(%[0-9A-Z]{2})+/g,decodeURIComponent)}return function t(o){function r(){}function i(n,t,i){if("undefined"!=typeof document){"number"==typeof(i=e({path:"/"},r.defaults,i)).expires&&(i.expires=new Date(1*new Date+864e5*i.expires)),i.expires=i.expires?i.expires.toUTCString():"";try{var c=JSON.stringify(t);/^[\{\[]/.test(c)&&(t=c)}catch(e){}t=o.write?o.write(t,n):encodeURIComponent(String(t)).replace(/%(23|24|26|2B|3A|3C|3E|3D|2F|3F|40|5B|5D|5E|60|7B|7D|7C)/g,decodeURIComponent),n=encodeURIComponent(String(n)).replace(/%(23|24|26|2B|5E|60|7C)/g,decodeURIComponent).replace(/[\(\)]/g,escape);var f="";for(var u in i)i[u]&&(f+="; "+u,!0!==i[u]&&(f+="="+i[u].split(";")[0]));return document.cookie=n+"="+t+f}}function c(e,t){if("undefined"!=typeof document){for(var r={},i=document.cookie?document.cookie.split("; "):[],c=0;c<i.length;c++){var f=i[c].split("="),u=f.slice(1).join("=");t||'"'!==u.charAt(0)||(u=u.slice(1,-1));try{var a=n(f[0]);if(u=(o.read||o)(u,a)||n(u),t)try{u=JSON.parse(u)}catch(e){}if(r[a]=u,e===a)break}catch(e){}}return e?r[e]:r}}return r.set=i,r.get=function(e){return c(e,!1)},r.getJSON=function(e){return c(e,!0)},r.remove=function(n,t){i(n,"",e(t,{expires:-1}))},r.defaults={},r.withConverter=t,r}(function(){})});
//# sourceMappingURL=/sm/b0ce608ffc029736e9ac80a8dd6a7db2da8e1d45d2dcfc92043deb2214aa30d8.map
```

Comment: i tried this code but i don't wanna know why do we need to download that js file code snippet mentioned below and what is the use of that file and how can i write my own?


**Code**

`download.file(
  url = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js',
  destfile = 'www/js.cookie.js'
)`

Comment: You will need a library to write from JavaScript to cookies. If you have another/better/own version you can replace that for sure,yes.

Comment: I mean i can use the above one but i don't know about security behind it also the author mentioned the same in disclaimer my data might be sensitive.

Comment: i am not sure how i can help there. They provided a mail for security issues on their page https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/ or you can file an issue. With 14k+ stars on github, there seem to be a larger user group who tested and use the code but if setting cookies with open source code is too risky for you i can understand that. Just out of curiosity, did you do some kind of similar security check for shiny?

Comment: Not for shiny because i am hosting on my organisation network so no security check for shiny but my form contains confidential data that's why i can blindly go for already provided javascript file.

Comment: Also i am not able to download file from `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js` might be because of proxy.So can you help me providing the corresponding file so that i can try.

Comment: I attached you the code of the file in my answer. I am not a security expert, but maybe you can also check the min.js code for security issues as it does not seem that long.

Comment: @BigDataScientish Thanks a lot for your effort.Really appreciate the same :)

Comment: you are welcome. an upvote/accept is appreciated =)

Comment: Update: Trying to run this example in 2023 I realized that now it is required to specify the functions in `extendShinyjs()`. For this example it'd be: `extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = c("getcookie", "setcookie"))`